# Using randomly generated integers as tensor index in tensorflow map_fn

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I initialize tensor `A` as below in a custom layer in Keras where batchSize is a placeholder:

```
A = K.zeros([batchSize, 2, 2 ,2])
```

I also initialize a numpy array `B` with size `[3,2,2,2]`. I would like to randomly select `[i,2,2,2]` size arrays from `B` where `i = 0,1,2`, and assign it to the first dimension of A and repeat this batchSize number of times.

Since I can’t explicitly loop over batchSize I tried tensorflow.map_fn as below:

```
ANew = tf.map_fn(lambda x: K.variable(B[np.random.randint(0,3,size=(1)).tolist()[0],:,:,:],
                 A, dtype=’float’, back_prop=False, infer_shape=True)
```

This generates `ANew` tensor. However, looks like `np.random.randint` is called only once; as a result, I always select the same index. How can I modify the code so that `np.random.randint(0,3,size=(1)).tolist()[0]` is called batchSize number of times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `K.gather`.

```
A = K.gather(B, indices_list)
```

Comment: :) -- If you consider your question answered, please mark this as a valid answer.